# Word 2007 - How do I convert text with inconsistent tabbing to a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a whole bunch of tables that were formatted weird, because when a bunch of people make tables out of tabs, one cannot expect the tabbing to be consistent on all of them.

For example... I have this table: 2 cols by 11 rows... but I would like a macro that didn't care about the number of columns and rows

```
space space space **column header** tab tab tab tab **column header**
tab **data** tab tab tab **data** tab tab
tab **data** tab tab **data**
tab **data** tab tab tab tab **data**
tab **data** tab tab **data**
```

Currently, I have this macro

```
Sub ConvertTextToATable()

     Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdWhite, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

End Sub
```

I've tried the tab separator... but both give similar results.  It creates a new column every time a new white space character is encountered.  What I want is ignoring all white space, and creating a new cell every time text is encountered, and creating a new row every time \n or \r is encountered.

And since I can't guarantee that every table with have the same number of column headers as the data, I think the number of columns should be determined by the second or third row in the text of original pseudo table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DerNalia, this calls for a Regular Expression.  Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 in your Office VBA editor:
[image: Image of VBA references]
<sub>(source: [david at wbtn.net](http://wbtn.net/~david/vba-regex.png))</sub>

Then, in your Macro use the Regex objects to replace all multiple instances of a tab with just one tab.  Then you can use your ConvertToTable command like normal.

Comment: That works amazing... but I still need to know how to ignore the white space before text starts =/

Comment: Why regex? You can use the macro recorder to record a Word macro to find tab tab and replace with tab.

Comment: Because I have lines like
space space **data** tab tab **data**
tab **data** tab tab **data**

I need regex to remove the first occurrence of white space and replace the rest with commas... its time for a new question.

link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975490/using-regex-to-remove-the-first-occurrence-of-white-space-and-then-replace-the-re