# Using regex to remove the first occurrence of white space and then replace the rest of the tabs with commas

Tags: regex

Because I have lines like

```
space space **da ta** tab tab **data**
tab **data** tab tab tab tab **da ta**
```

I want the above to turn into

```
**da ta**,**data**
**data**,**da ta**
```

I need regex to remove all the white space before the first letter and replace the rest with commas... but still ignoring the white space in between the letters in the data

Comment: What language/platform?  It will probably require two separate operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/^[ \t]+//;  # remove leading whitespace (just once)
s/[ \t]+/,/g; # replace all runs of spaces into commas globally
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was removing all instances of a double space repeatedly... works well. I did use some of that though