# Regex wrapping word

Tags: regex

[Regex example](http://regexr.com/3ca92)

How can I exclude the first space in every match?

The same regex: `(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regex to remove the first occurrence of white space and then replace the rest of the tabs with commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975490/using-regex-to-remove-the-first-occurrence-of-white-space-and-then-replace-the-r)

Comment: What do you mean by `exclude the first space in every match` Do you want to match a non-word as the first character _except_ whitespace ?

Comment: Well, that would be `[^\w\s]?#(\w+)\b`

Comment: @sln that also matches `#` followed by `\w`-class characters in the middle of other words which he probably doesn't want. My first solution also had that issue but I've just updated my answer.

Comment: @wullxz - `# followed by \w` I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I mean, it would match his desired pattern (ex `#test`) inside another word (ex `otherword#test`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
http://regexr.com/3ca98

From the information you gave us until now, this regex should also be sufficient: `#(\w+)(?!\w)`.
But maybe there's more to it than we know. What did you want to achieve with the `(?:^|\W)`?

**Edit**: Thinking about what you probably want to achieve, it occured to me that you might only match your pattern if it's not in the middle of another word (e.g. `test#case`). You probably don't want to match this.
To exclude such cases, you have to asure that there's some kind of whitespace character in front of it, or in other words: nothing else but whitespace characters or nothing.

I assume you use javascript because regexr.com does and sadly, there is no regex lookbehind available in javascripts regex implementation. So there is no real option to make sure there is only nothing or whitespace in front of your pattern.
One solution would be to work with capture groups. Take this regex:
`(?:^|\s+)(#\w+)`

It searches for one or more whitespace characters or linestarts in front of your pattern but doesn't use a capture group for that. Then your pattern is up and it's the first capture group in the whole expression.

To use this in javascript now, you need to instantiate a RegExp object and use its function exec until there are no more matches and save the first capture group to a result array.

JS code:

```
var txt = text.innerHTML;
var re = /(?:^|\s+)(#\w+)/g;
var res = [];
var tmpresult = [];
while ((tmpresult = re.exec(txt)) !== null) {
    res.push(tmpresult[1]); // push first capture group to result stack
}
result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j41tw4hm/1/
Updated regexr.com: http://regexr.com/3ca9n